# Limits on Addressability?

Tags: c, memory-address, cpu-architecture

I am reading some C text at the address:

https://cs.senecac.on.ca/~lczegel/BTP100/pages/content/compu.html

In the section: **Addressible Memory** they say that "*The maximum size of addressable primary memory depends upon the size of the address registers.*"

I do not understand why is that.

Can anyone give me a clear explanation, please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 32-bit registers, then the highest address you can store in a single register is 2^32-1, so you can address 2^32 units (in modern computers, units are almost always bytes). A larger number simply won't fit.

You can get around this by using memory addresses that are larger than a single register can hold (and some CPUs/operating systems have features for doing so), but using addresses/pointers will be slower because it has to fiddle with multiple registers.

As an example, suppose you have 32-bit registers but 64-bit pointers and want to increment a pointer to find the next item in an array of `char` (`++p`). Instead of performing a simple increment instruction, the processor will have to

1. Increment the lower 32 bits;
2. check if the result is zero (overflow);
3. increment the upper half as well if overflow occurred.

Simplifying a bit, this means it has to perform a branch (if-then-else) instruction, which is one of the slowest and most complex instructions a modern CPU performs.

(See, e.g., [x86 memory segmentation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) on the Wikipedia for a multi-register addressing scheme used in Intel processors.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have 1 address register, holding a 16 bit address, you can have a maximum of 2^16 - 1 addresses.

However many registers, the number of addresses they can point to will be limited by their width (number of bits).

Thus, the maximum size of addressable primary memory depends upon the size of the address registers.

Comment: No if you have 16 address registers with one-bit width you can have 2 addresses but really many registers to point to them.  Not really helpful for a beginner

Comment: @Peer Stritzinger - Got my terminology mixed up. Answer updated.

Comment: Somehow can't revoke my -1 it should work since you edited.  Maybe a race, if you edit again it might work

Answer (score 2):

Keeping it simple: the address registers are used to store and refer to addresses of memory; since their size and number is fixed, there is a *maximum address*.

Obviously you can't exploit more memory than what is addressable (because the machine wouldn't know how to refer to it), so the usable memory is in fact limited by the maximum address that can be expressed by the address registers.

Comment: Not exactly; many CPUs and operating systems *can* address larger memories, but it comes at a cost.

Comment: @larsmans: I was keeping it simple. Of course there are a lot of platform-specific tricks to circumvent this limitation (e.g. PAE on IA32), but the basic concept is that the addressable memory is limited by the size of the address.